# Counting Game Try/Except and calculating the users attempts

Tags: python

I am creating a python random counting game. I'm having some difficulties with certain parts. Can anyone here review my code? I'm having difficulty with trying to implement a try/except and a tries function that counts the user's attempts. I also have to verify that the number is a legitimate input and not a variable. So far I've gotten this far and its coming along good. I just need alittle help ironing out a few things. Thanks guys you rock.

Here is the code below:

```
import random
def main():
start_game()
play_again()
tries()
print("Welcome to the number guessing game")
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 50")

def start_game():
secret_number = random.randint(1,50)
user_attempt_number = 1
user_guess = 0
while user_guess != secret_number and user_attempt_number < 5:
print("---Attempt", user_attempt_number)
user_input_text = input("Guess what number I am thinking of: ")
user_guess = int(user_input_text)

if user_guess > secret_number:
print("Too high")
elif user_guess < secret_number:
print("Too low")
else:
print("Right")

user_attempt_number += 1
if user_guess != secret_number:
print("You ran out of attempts. The correct number was"
+str(secret_number)+ ".")
    
def play_again():
while True:
play_again = input("Do you want to play again?")
if play_again == 'yes':
main()
if play_again =='no':
print("Thanks for playing")
break

def tries():
found= False
max_attempts=50
secret_number = random.randint(1, 50)
while tries <= max_attempts and not found:
user_input_text = start_game()
user_guess_count=+1
if user_input_text == secret_number:
print("It took you {} tries.".format(user_guess_count))
found = True    

main()
```

Comment: please include your complete, working, minimal code _as a code snippet_ in the question. if your code is actually working and you simply want it to be better, see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
def play_game():
print("Enter the upper limit for the range of numbers: ")
limit = int(input())
number = random.randint(1, limit)
print("I'm thinking of a number from 1 to " + str(limit) + "\n")
count = 1 #new line
while True:
    guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
    if guess < number:
        print("Too low.")
    elif guess > number:
        print("Too high.")
    elif guess == number:
        print("You guessed it in " + str(count) + " tries.\n")
    count = count+
```

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help the OP, but post this as a comment when you have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @10Rep You can't put code blocks in comments. Edit: nvm; I didn't realize this answer was originally just a request for clarified code and was edited after you posted your comment.

Comment: What about the try/except? How would I go about incorporating that feature into the code block?